# How do I load this txt file into my database as a table?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am not sure how to import this TXT file in as a table or how to:

1. Set `CustomerPk` to *auto increment*
2. Change `CustNo` to be an *index* and be set to required

This is the TXT file I got from my instructor and any help would be very appreciated. I tried to just load the file as a CSV file but the table did not show up correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(   CustomerPK INT(11)
    CustNo          CHAR(8),
        CustFirstName    VARCHAR(20),
        CustLastName     VARCHAR(30),
    CustStreet  VARCHAR(50),
    CustCity    VARCHAR(30),
    CustState   CHAR(2),
    CustZip     CHAR(10),
    CustBal     DECIMAL(12,2) DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT CustomerPK PRIMARY KEY (CustNo)
 )
```

**NOTES:**

- CustomerPK should be defined as the Primary Key and set to Auto Increment
- CustNo should be defined as an Index and set to Required
- CustFirstName should be set to Required
- CustLastName should be set to Required

*Import the data using the SQL statements below:*

```
INSERT INTO customer
    (CustNo, CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustStreet, CustCity,
    CustState, CustZip, CustBal) 
    VALUES('C0954327','Sheri','Gordon','336 Hill St.','Littleton','CO','80129-5543',230.00);

INSERT INTO customer
    (CustNo, CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustStreet, CustCity,
    CustState, CustZip, CustBal) 
    VALUES('C1010398','Jim','Glussman','1432 E. Ravenna','Denver','CO','80111-0033',200.00);

INSERT INTO customer
    (CustNo, CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustStreet, CustCity,
    CustState, CustZip, CustBal) 
    VALUES('C2388597','Beth','Taylor','2396 Rafter Rd','Seattle','WA','98103-1121',500.00);

INSERT INTO customer
    (CustNo, CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustStreet, CustCity,
    CustState, CustZip, CustBal) 
    VALUES('C3340959','Betty','Wise','4334 153rd NW','Seattle','WA','98178-3311',200.00);

INSERT INTO customer
    (CustNo, CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustStreet, CustCity,
    CustState, CustZip, CustBal) 
    VALUES('C3499503','Bob','Mann','1190 Lorraine Cir.','Monroe','WA','98013-1095',0.00);
```

Comment: Are you trying to load data from a text file, or use insert statements?

Comment: I'm not really sure, the only information I was given for the assignment was to "create and load the tables according to the attached file".

Comment: Read about MySQL's `LOAD DATA` function.